# How to outline table column using JS/CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, ember.js, html-table, less

I need to select a table column on click. To show selection, I need to outline the table column.

I managed to outline each  in the column needed, see pic:

[image]

However, that doesn't suit me: I need to get rid of inner lines.
CSS (actually, LESS) I currently use:

```
  td.fd-selected
  {
    outline: 0.25em dashed rgb(79,115,176);
    background-color: rgba(79,115,176, 0.25);
  }
```

Comment: have you looked into pseudo-classes first-child and last-child and considered using border-top, border-bottom, border-right etc

Comment: @Matt.C thanks, I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it with `outline`. `outline` is basically used to highlight a focused element in its entirety (mostly form elements). In its default setting, it uses the outline provided either by the operating system or the web browser itself (IE as example for the former, Chrome as example for the latter).

The only reliable (and the least hacky) solution is, to use borders.

**Here's how (logic):**

1. Place left and right borders to all cells.
2. Place top border to the appropriate cell of the first row
3. Place bottom border to the appropriate cell of the last row

The example below also shows, how you could highlight the header too.

**Example**

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

th, td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td.outline {
  border-left: 2px dotted #06c;
  border-right: 2px dotted #06c;
}

tr:first-child > td.outline {
  border-top: 2px dotted #06c;
}

tr:last-child > td.outline {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #06c;
}

/*how could it look like with the header*/

th.outline {
  background-color: #99ccee;
  border: 2px dotted #06c
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="outline"></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="outline"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="outline"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="outline"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="outline"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```